# Get itunes id from url

Tags: php, regex

what is the best way to retrieve id from itunes app link?

let say i have these link:

> http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026?mt=8
>
> http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026

i just want to get the id, 457603026 using php preg_match

Comment: you absolutely need a preg_match?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without preg_match:

```
$url = 'http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026?mt=8';
echo end(explode('/id', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)));
```

or, if you prefer:

```
$url = 'http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026?mt=8';
$id = explode('/id', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
echo $id[1];
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `explode`,  assuming the `idxxx` is always at the end of the link :-

```
$id = str_replace("id", "", end(explode("/", parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH))));
```

Comment: it's not necessarily at the end of link, there sometimes is ?mt=8 added

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
$url = 'http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026';
preg_match("/id(\d+)/", $url, $match); 
echo $match[1]; //457603026
```

Comment: this won't work if the app name start with `id123` (for example) - bookofzeus (first one) and ajreal has the best solution

Answer (score 4):

Solution for all kind or iTunes URL

```
$urls = array('http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026',
'http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/break-of-dawn/id472335316?ign-mpt=uo%3D',
'http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/monopoly-here-now-the-world/id299110947?mt=8',
'http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/revista-/id397781759?mt=8%3Futm_so%3Dtwitter',
'http://itunes.apple.com/app/id426698291&mt=8',
'http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/respect-the-bull-single/id4899',
'http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/id6655669');

foreach($urls as $url):
preg_match("/id(\d+)/", $url, $match); 
echo $match[1];
echo  '<br/>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: thanks for including all the examples of possible itunes links

Answer (score 1):

Try this, not a regex solution though:

```
$url = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bring-me-sandwiches!!/id457603026?mt=8";
$arr = array_pop(explode("/", $url));
$id = array_pop(array_reverse(explode("?", $arr)));
echo substr($id, 2, strlen($id));
```